# How to create a jQuery plain object from textfield?

Tags: jquery

This is my textfield,

```
 <input type="text" name="Design" id="Design" value="${map.designList}" >
```

where map.designList having string as

```
   {'1' : 'design 1','2' : 'design no 2qq','3' : 'design no 2qq'}
```

Now i am getting value of this Design texyfiend by $('#Design').val() 
, But i want it in **jQuery plain object** .

Please suggest me any way to convert var to object...
i have tried this,but not working

```
 var designval= $('#Design').val();
 var $dd = $(designval); // Not working
 alert('jQuery.isPlainObject( $dd )....'+jQuery.isPlainObject( $dd));
```

Comment: If ur trying to covert that string into a jquery object then you can probably use `$.parseJSON({'1' : 'design 1','2' : 'design no 2qq','3' : 'design no 2qq'})` to convert it to a jquery object

Answer (score 0):

use `$.parseJSON` method to convert the string to json object.

```
var obj = $.parseJSON($('#Design').val()); obj;
```

In the obj, you will get the string in the json object format then you can tryout other operations as

```
$.isPlainObject(obj)
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: replace those single quotes with double ones before parsing it.. it  will surely work..

Comment: yes its working...and i hv got another solution too...using eval fuction...like this..  `eval('( ' + $('#Design').val() + ' )'  );`